# R Spatial Information Aggregation

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, r-sp

I am trying to build a mapping function with R, using the dplyr, sp and rgdal packages. To start with, I'll describe the data. I have downloaded the shapefile of the entire world from [opendatasoft.com](https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/world-administrative-boundaries/export/). I extracted the country names from the dataframe embedded in this sp object, and then made a dataframe with some values that are distributed across the countries. Finally, I wrote the following UDF to merge the data with the sp object.

```
createDataMap <- function(shapeFileName = "world-administrative-boundaries", countryValueData){
  SpatialInformation <- readOGR(shapeFileName, paste(shapeFileName,"areas", sep = "-")) #I am appending the term "-areas" only because I renamed the files in the folder
  ValueInformation <- countryValueData
  
  namesOfCountriesInTheWorldMap <- SpatialInformation@data$name
  namesOfCountriesInValueList <- ValueInformation$Country
  namesInValuesButNotInTheWorld <- setdiff(namesOfCountriesInValueList, namesOfCountriesInTheWorldMap)
  namesInTheWorldButNotInTheDataFile <- setdiff(namesOfCountriesInTheWorldMap, namesOfCountriesInValueList)
  
  if(length(namesInValuesButNotInTheWorld)>0){
    return("You seem to have Values outside this world. Please wait until we achieve Type 1 Civilization Status.")
  }
  
  
  
  if(length(namesInTheWorldButNotInTheDataFile)>0){
    return("Please add all the country rows in the data file, even if you do not have Values everywhere.")
  }
  
  IDtoCountry <- as.data.frame(cbind(namesOfCountriesInTheWorldMap, sapply(SpatialInformation@polygons, function(x) x@ID)))
  
  namesOfCountriesInValueList <- left_join(namesOfCountriesInValueList,IDtoCountry, by = c("Country" = "namesOfCountriesInTheWorldMap"))
  locationInfo <- SpatialInformation@data
  namesOfCountriesInValueList <- left_join(countryValueData,locationInfo, by = c("Country" = "name"))
  rownames(namesOfCountriesInValueList) <- namesOfCountriesInValueList$V2
  
  namesOfCountriesInValueList$V2 <- NULL
  
  return(SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpatialInformation, namesOfCountriesInValueList, match.ID = TRUE))
  
   
}
```

As for the countryValueData, It is just a dataframe of random values and NAs associated with each countries, which I created with random number generation and the list of countries I got from the sp object.

This merge works fine. Now I have a dataframe embedded in the sp object with the following structure.

> 'data.frame':  256 obs. of  12 variables:
>
> > $ Country    : chr  "Uganda" "Uzbekistan" "Ireland" "Eritrea" ...

> > $ Value1     : num  NA NA 1660 NA NA ...

> > $ Value2     : num  2727 734 734 2727 734 ...

> > $ Value3     : num  2574 4383 3024 4293 NA ...

> > $ Value4     : num  2727 734 734 2727 1404 ...

> > $ iso3       : chr  "UGA" "UZB" "IRL" "ERI" ...

> > $ status     : chr  "Member State" "Member State" "Member State" "Member State" ...

> > $ color_code : chr  "UGA" "UZB" "IRL" "ERI" ...

> > $ continent  : chr  "Africa" "Asia" "Europe" "Africa" ...

> > $ region     : chr  "Eastern Africa" "Central Asia" "Northern Europe" "Eastern Africa" ...

> > $ iso_3166_1_: chr  "UG" "UZ" "IE" "ER" ...

> > $ french_shor: chr  "Ouganda" "Ouzbékistan" "Irlande" "Érythrée" ...

where value1, value2, value3 and value4 are the random values I mentioned before. What I am now trying to do is to somehow aggregate this data on a continent level. In theory, since all the polygons in the sp object have their borders well defined, and there is a mapping from countries to continent in the data frame, aggregation should not impossible. I want to have a mechanism with which I can change the nature of my bubble plot from country level to continent level, but for that, first, I need to do this aggregation. Has anyone ever tried to do this?

Comment: Mixing `dplyr` with `sp` and  soon-to-be-retired `rgdal`  is a bit odd choice,  is  `sp` an actual requirement? With `sf` there would be almost no difference compared to aggregating regular dataframes with `dplyr` (group_by + summarise).

Comment: Hi @margusl, there is no specific requirement to use the sp package. I followed a course online, and that is the package they were focusing on. I am unfamiliar with the sf package. Do you know of any good resource online that I can read to get up to date on it?

Comment: Oficial Vignettes, https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/ . And perhaps vector topics of https://r.geocompx.org/index.html ( https://r.geocompx.org/spatial-operations.html#spatial-aggr for aggregations). Both sources cover spatial agregations with base R `aggregate()`  and with dplyr-style `group_by() %>% summarise()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With, e.g., {sf} it's straightforward to join spatial dataframes with supplementary data and "slice'n'dice" the non-geometry columns ("attributes") as one would do with other dataframes. When aggregating across rows, the spatial features are merged by default.

example:

- read in shapefile as spatial dataframe:

```
library(sf)

the_countries <- read_sf('/path/to/my/shapefile.shp')
```

```
> the_countries
Simple feature collection with 9 features and 8 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -4.79028 ymin: 41.36492 xmax: 17.16639 ymax: 55.05653
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# A tibble: 9 x 9
  iso3  status       color_code name    continent region iso_3166_1_ french_shor
  <chr> <chr>        <chr>      <chr>   <chr>     <chr>  <chr>       <chr>      
1 CHE   Member State CHE        Switze~ Europe    Weste~ CH          Suisse     
2 AUT   Member State AUT        Austria Europe    Weste~ AT          Autriche
## ...
```

- generate some additional toy data:

```
country_value_data <- data.frame(iso3 = c('FRA', 'BEL'), random_indicator = rnorm(2))
```

- join toy data to existing attributes and aggregate, e. g. across continent:

```
library(dplyr)

the_countries |>
  left_join(country_value_data, by = 'iso3') |>
  group_by(continent) |>
  summarise(random_indicator = mean(random_indicator, na.rm = TRUE))
```

```
+ Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -4.79028 ymin: 41.36492 xmax: 17.16639 ymax: 55.05653
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  continent random_indicator                                            geometry
  <chr>                <dbl>                                  <MULTIPOLYGON [°]>
1 Europe              -0.968 (((9.455 42.71861, 9.4675 42.76555, 9.4884 42.8070~
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you, @I_O for the detailed example. And thank you, margusl, for pointing me in the right direction:-)